# counting no of values in a single field in database in php

Tags: php, mysql

suppose i have a field in my table named  "candidates" and in this field i am having two values separated by comma....like aron,john....instead of two names there can be multiple names separated by comma............now i want to count the number of values in this field ??how can i do this...can this be done using explode function??

```
<?php
      $sql_explode="select * from tb_party where party_id='3'";
      $query_explode=mysql_query($sql_explode);
      $k=1;
      $row_explode=mysql_fetch_array($query_explode);


      $a=$row_explode["service_providers"];
      $pieces = explode(",", $a);
      echo $pieces[0];
      echo $pieces[1];
      echo $pieces[2];
      echo $pieces[3];
?>
```

well this php script is just echoing the values i cannot understand how to count the number of values ....can anyone suggest me something on this?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Normalize your database to store the data in separate rows in a separate table instead of comma-separated in a single field, then you could easily count them in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use count($pieces);

http://www.php.net/count

I advice you Normalize your database as  deceze said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [count()](https://www.php.net/count)

```
$a=$row_explode["service_providers"];
$pieces = explode(",", $a);

count($pieces); // it will display the total number of element
```